# What mind stands for

Tags: american-english

The difinition of mind that  parts of individual feels, perceives, thinks, wills, and especially reasons is a common presence in dictionaries，however,what it stand for？Brain？

Comment: This is really more of a philosophy question than an English question. The relationship between brain and mind is explored by René Descartes in his theory of [Cartesian dualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism_%28philosophy_of_mind%29).

Comment: @phenry I would agree that it is 'off-topic', but for rather different reasons to those given by you and others. The OP appears to me to be looking for a definition, or meaning of *mind*. That would seem to me to be a legitimate-enough English language question, but clearly the answer can easily be found in a dictionary or with Wikipedia. That should have been the reason, I believe, for marking it off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an important question which you have asked.

***Mind*** and ***brain*** are two related concepts but quite definitely do not mean the same thing.

Their distinction is a philosophical matter but one for which there is a well-established epistemological structure.

The science of ***psychology*** deals with the study of the mind. It has at times been carried out at an entirely theoretical level without reference to the physiology of the brain. It has its own corpus of learning.

***Neuroscience***, on the other hand, is a field which includes experimental psychology, but focuses essentially on the structure and function of the nervous system and brain.

A 'brain' is a physical object ( a very complex one - but an object) inside a person's head. The 'mind' is a more abstract concept which deals with *that element of a person that enables them to be aware of the world and their experiences, to think, and to feel; the faculty of consciousness and thought* (Oxford Dictionaries - not OED)

Comment: I sometimes wonder why questions which are so obviously off topic are answered at all.

Comment: Sorry,I'm non-native learner,I don't realise it is a philosophy question and the definition of mind is translated into the meaning similar to brain ,head in Chinese(or maybe I only grasp the ostensibe meaning). Anyway,thank you for your help——not only the answer to my question,but also the access you offer to get the answer when I have a new question.

Comment: Oops，I didn't mention the main reason of my misunderstanding.When I see the part(or element)of person,organ occurs to me.( I am just a beginner)